# Why is the Language Bar not available for me in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, input-languages, language-bar

I'm running Windows 7 and have installed the Spanish keyboard (under Spain - International Sort).  I've set the Language Bar to show up in the taskbar.  But the language bar doesn't show up.

Everything is as it should be according to [this help article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/The-Language-bar-overview) from Microsoft.  It says it won't show up if I don't have two input languages set up, which I do (English and Spanish).  I've found several forum posts ([example](http://www.sysprobs.com/language-bar-missing-vista-windows-7), [example](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistadesktopui/thread/b4441951-1b0d-4e4c-b133-9f9cb08fefc9/)) that mention running ctfmon.exe and/or editing the registry to make it run at startup; I tried running it and it didn't do anything.  It didn't even show up in Task Manager.  I couldn't find anything in Services (services.msc) that seemed to relate to languages, and I'd rather not make registry edits unless I have to.

What is going on here?

Interesting side note: when I first went to post this question, I found that the Spanish keyboard was enabled and in use (I knew because when I tried to type ?, I got _).  But I couldn't change it back to English; the language bar wasn't available, and the keyboard shortcuts listed in Control Panel to switch input methods didn't do anything.  And it was only Spanish in the browser (Firefox).  I had to delete the Spanish keyboard and restart to get English back.